# How to create a notification system that pushes messages to a user's specific account?

Tags: php

I am trying do store a function in a file and extract to run when needed, but I cannot find a better way to do so.

This is what I've tried:

```php
function store_callable(string $func)
{
    writefile($func);
}
eval(readfile());
```

My first concern is the type of the parameter `$func`. I'm expecting to receive only `callable` as argument, but I can't find a way to convert a PHP callable into string to save.

Secondly, although `eval()` is used here to run the saved function, I wondered if there's a better way of doing that, although seems there's no.

I don't think it's a kind of serialization but it seems they have similarities so I added the tag still.

---

EDIT:

My original idea was to create a notification system that pushes messages to a user's specific account. However, some notifications are specifically pushed only to one device or IP. Which means I need a filter function for that. I can actually complete this by using a new property like `restricted-to` but I wanted to make a more general field `filter-function` in the notification object which returns a boolean and lets the system decide whether to push the notification on this load.

EDIT2:

I CAN actually directly code them in the PHP file, but it will become messy, as different notification has different filter to decide whether they are pushed or not, I can give u an example:

```php
new Notification("message");
class Notification
{
    public function push_or_not()
    {
        if($this->isabout== "login" && checkIP())
        {
            \\ sth
        }
        else if() 
        else if()
        //and so on
    }
}
```

This can actually run and avoid security risks. But this isn't general enough. Meaning that I need to edit the `if-else` here at first, and create a new `type` property here.

I'm just asking whether the initial more general filter function (cuz I can define it in EACH notification but here I can just add the type and relate it to the type) stored directly in notification data is better (and any improvements) or the latter one here is better.

It seems there's not much security risk here as the code here isn't related to user input.

Comment: If you explain a bit more what problem you're trying to solve by doing this in the first place, and how it's used, we might be able to give you better guidance.

Comment: However, a better way to execute a callable would be [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) or [call_user_func_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Comment: eval accepts a string, not a callable. But as above...why do you need to do this? If you want to make a function, just paste it into a .php file as normal, and `include` that file into your main application script so that the function is available to use. Adding functions on-the-fly to your application is unusual, generally unnecessary, and always a security risk.

Comment: @M. Eriksson, I see, is there any function that can convert between callable and string?

Comment: @ADyson, thx but, pls see my edit for more info

Comment: `I wanted to make a more general field filter-function which returns a boolean and lets the system decide whether to push the notification on this load`...I can't think why any of that would require you to use PHP to store function code in a string, and then retrieve and eval it. You can write a regular function  which accepts the needed variables (e.g. perhaps the notification type, and user ID?) and outputs the needed response (true or false?). Is there something you think is preventing you from taking the standard approach? Nothing you've mentioned so far would appear to rule it out.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you're trying to solve here, even after your edit. As  the previous commenter stated, this is an unusual and strange solution.

Comment: (eval is) At least often a security risk, and having eval in the code is a review and maintenance burden. Sounds a bit like an X/Y problem. Write the implementation with your direct first idea of the property, and then review the design, not alternate already. Just my 2 cents. You can also add it as pseudo code to the question, that will also help to give better feedback.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, I thought I've stated them well already. My current solution is working, but I am wondering whether there's a better way to achieve the thing.

Comment: @ADyson, the problem is, I need to save the checking function in the notification file for checking when the user loads the page.

Comment: Almost certainly you don't need dynamic code for this in the first place, that's what we're saying. Your example doesn't contain enough info to justify that approach at all. What's wrong with just writing a regular function that you don't have to load and save in this way? Declare it, `include` it, then call it. That would certainly be a cleaner, easier and more maintainable design. You _appear_ to be saving function definitions _at runtime_...but why on earth would that ever be needed? We are still lacking any real context. What is generating that function code dynamically, and why?

Comment: You haven't given us any info that would clarify it at all. Property on what? Where? When? How are the notifications added? To what? Where? When? "Genereal field" on what? Where? When? You have only given us a very vague description. Remember that we know absolutely nothing about your application.

Comment: Implement all those "functions" as classes with __invoke(), make the constructor part of the interface / abstract to define initialization. Then use auto-loading to make the inclusion of those better to control, as well as what they have on __unvoke(). This spares to write include() calls, which are similar to eval() (not exactly the same, but close). You can then store the classname as string, there is no eval, the application can verify if the "function" exists etc. etc. etc..

Comment: A good mindset would also be to make your code as simple as possible. Everything doesn't have to be general or reusable. Abstract when necessary and only add complexity if it's required to solve the problem at hand. If you have a simple solution that works, stick to it and only change it if you need to, to solve a new problem.

Comment: @hakre that makes the dynamic loading process a little nicer (although arguably adds complexity in a different way, especially to the uninitiated), but I strongly suspect that in fact there is no need for multiple different function declarations here in the first place. We need more context, but it _sounds like_ the OP is actually just making multiple versions of the same code, with only variations in some data values used within it. Which of course, is exactly the scenario which is solved by declaring a single function which accepts parameters. But I could be wrong. Let's see...

Comment: `it will become messy, as different notification has different filter`...one way to make that neater and easier to maintain and test could be to make each notification type a sub-class of the `Notification` class, with its own definition of the push_or_not() function overriding the parent class's definition, so the logic for each type is held and implemented separately.

Comment: @ADyson, I see, I actually have thought of that but I still couldn't figure out a way to serialize the callable in each subclass object? thx for helping

Comment: Why would you need to serialize anything, with that design? The push_or_not() definition would be coded into each subclass already, so that each notification type's logic is separate, but ready-made.

Comment: e.g. maybe something like this: https://3v4l.org/CR1Qo is what I was thinking.

Comment: @ADyson, Ohh, I get what u mean now, I was thinking that to create a subclass for EACH notification, thx for advising that, I think this is the most suitable solution after all. But what if I still wanted to make one with saved filter? Is that really that bad?

Comment: A class is like a template you declare in advance, and then you can create as many copies ("instances") of it as you need, at runtime. Then they can all have different data values, but share the same code logic. Maybe this situation has arisen because you need to take a refresher course on the core principles of object-oriented programming :-)

Comment: `what if I still wanted to make one with saved filter? Is that really that bad`...depends on your definition of "bad". But as noted above, it would make your code harder to understand, harder to test and debug, and overall more difficult to maintain in the long run.

Comment: @ADyson, I got what you mean, I just looked wrong in the words. I thought what u meant is that creating each subclass instance then save that. Now the problem is solved, thxx :)

Comment: @ADyson, Oh I see, i think I am going with the subclass one, it seems actually resolving the problem of tidiness and balancing the security and problem. I just thought if there's a chance a more general thing like that can happen. Thx for your advice! :D

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need dynamic code for this at all.

One way to make the feature neater and easier to maintain and test - as well as removing any potential security risks associated with the use of `eval()` - could be to make each notification type a sub-class of the `Notification` class, with its own definition of the `push_or_not()` function overriding the parent class's definition, so the logic for each type is held and implemented separately.

A very simple example:

```
abstract class Notification {
    abstract public function push_or_not();
}

class Notification_Login extends Notification
{
    public function push_or_not() {
        if (checkIP() && "Something") {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;        
    }
}

class Notification_SomethingElse extends Notification
{
    public function push_or_not() {
        if (checkIP() && "SomethingElse") {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Remember a class is a bit like a template which you declare in advance, before you actually run the code, and then you can create as many copies ("instances") of it as you need at runtime. Then the instances you create can all have different data values, but share the same code logic. So you end up with one class for each type of notification, and your code can then create as many instances of the class as it needs - i.e. one instance for each individual notification of that type.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds really dangerous, but that aside, why not just include the file.  This will run any code in it.

```
$myphp = <<<TEXT
<?php 

echo "this is a bit of code run";
?>
TEXT

file_put_contents('insecuredirectory/mynewfile.php');

include 'insecuredirectory/mynewfile.php';
```

NOTE:

This is a truly bad idea if you dont know who is writing the PHP code as the code itself will have full control over your code and the server it is running on.